# Index.php rewrite fails after Apache 2.2 to 2.4 update

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, kohana

My .htaccess file for a Kohana 3.3 project is:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Following Eric's advice I have updated the htaccess to the following:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files ".*">
  Require all denied
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I updated the Virtual Host to include:

```
<Directory /srv/www/example.com/public_html/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Did I miss something else?

Comment: What do your Apache error logs say?

Comment: Are you getting 404 now?

Comment: You should read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html about the allow deny part

Comment: @Eric thanks missed that one - still getting 404.

Comment: Please update the main post with your new rules

Comment: Also <files ".*"> vs <files .*>

Comment: Also RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [PT]

Comment: @anubhava yes I'm getting 404

Comment: @MonkeyZeus nothing in Apache error logs

Comment: Is your log level set high enough?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified htaccess

```
# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
  Require all granted
</Files>
```

and added AllowOverride All to virtualhost config.

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```